# Unable to map <cr> to require("telescope-undo.actions").restore when using lazy.nvim

Tags: lua, neovim

To preface, `yank_additions`,  `yank_deletions`, and `restore` all work prior to editing `mappings` so I know the issue is not with my terminal.

[Proof of telescope-undo working normally with <C-cr> restoring the buffer](https://asciinema.org/a/IdH2o7foG68g33TlOkE18qyq7)

I have tried the following:

```
return {
  "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
  dependencies = {
    "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
    {
      "nvim-telescope/telescope-fzf-native.nvim",
      build = "make",
    },
    "debugloop/telescope-undo.nvim",
  },
  keys = {
    {
      "<leader>fu",
      "<cmd>Telescope undo<cr>",
      desc = "View undos",
    },
  },
  opts = {
    extensions = {
      undo = {
        mappings = {
          i = {
            ["<S-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_additions,
            ["<C-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_deletions,
            ["<cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").restore,
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  config = function()
    require("telescope").load_extension("undo")
  end,
}
```

which gives me this error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/franky/Projects/dotfiles/neovim/.config/nvim/init.lua:
Failed to load `plugins.telescope`
/home/franky/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/telescope.lua:55: module 'telescope-undo.actions' not found:
```

And so, I manually passed `opts` to `config` and called `setup` myself.

```
config = function(_, opts)
    require("telescope").load_extension("undo")
    require("telescope").setup(opts)
  end,
```

but I get the same error.

I wrapped my calls init callbacks with

```
opts = {
  extensions = {
    undo = {
      mappings = {
        i = {
          ["<S-cr>"] = function()
            require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_additions()
          end,

          ["<C-cr>"] = function()
            require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_deletions()
            end,

            ["<cr>"] = function()
            require("telescope-undo.actions").restore()
            end,
        },
        }
    }
    }
},
config = function(_, opts)
  require("telescope").setup(opts)
  require("telescope").load_extension("undo")
end,
```

And that causes `telescope-undo` not work in the telescope floating window. Every press of enter resets the cursor

[Video showcase #1](https://asciinema.org/a/5z6BLRZmKBTvBBD7i6heuLRv0)

---

I have also tried the following, but this still doesn't work. I decided to include it because I'm not sure if this is *progress*. Pressing enter on on an undo item opens a blank screen (video example below)

```
opts = {
  extensions = {
    undo = {
      mappings = {
        ["<s-cr>"] = function()
          require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_additions()
        end,
        ["<c-cr>"] = function()
          require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_deletions()
        end,
        ["<cr>"] = function()
          require("telescope-undo.actions").restore()
        end,
      },
    },
  },
},
config = function(_, opts)
  require("telescope").setup(opts)
  require("telescope").load_extension("undo")
end,
```

[Video showcase #2](https://asciinema.org/a/im6boHpahOZim7jkPVCW88pGf)

I removed the `opts` and did everything in the config.

```
config = function()
  require("telescope").load_extension("undo")

  local opts = {
    extensions = {
      undo = {
        mappings = {
          ["<s-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_additions,
          ["<c-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_deletions,
          ["<cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").restore
        },
      },
    },
  }

  require("telescope").setup(opts)
end,
```

And putting the `setup` before the `load_extension`

```
config = function()
  local opts = {
    extensions = {
      undo = {
        mappings = {
          ["<s-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_additions,
          ["<c-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_deletions,
          ["<cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").restore
        },
      },
    },
  }

  require("telescope").setup(opts)
  require("telescope").load_extension("undo")
end,
```

Putting the setup after the `load_extension`s does nothing

[Here's what happens before setup is before the load_extensions](https://asciinema.org/a/ejTspBkeQBiilZtahVC91dMJU)

In case it's necessary, here is my [config](https://github.com/j-barnak/dotfiles/tree/main/neovim/.config/nvim).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how'd you do it

```
return {
  "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
  dependencies = {
    "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
    "debugloop/telescope-undo.nvim",
  },
  config = function()
    local opts = {
      extensions = {
        undo = {
          mappings = {
            i = {
              ["<s-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_additions,
              ["<c-cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").yank_deletions,
              ["<cr>"] = require("telescope-undo.actions").restore
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }

    require("telescope").setup(opts)
    require("telescope").load_extension("undo")
  end,
}
```

Was forgetting the `i` under `mapping`